# Performance issue for ion-tabs

Tags: performance, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have created a ionic tabs project using ion-tabs component. But the issue is when user clicks on tab icon, tab is not changed immediately. It takes 1-2 seconds to switch the tabs.

HTML Code:

```
<ion-tabs  class="footer-tabs" selectedIndex="selectedTabIndex"#footerTabs>
  <ion-tab tabIcon="list" tabTitle="'Notice'" [root]="noticepage"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tabIcon="book1" tabTitle="'Homework'" [root]="homeworkpage"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tabIcon="calendar1" tabTitle="'Event'" [root]="eventpage"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tabIcon="list-box1" tabTitle="'Attendance'" [root]="attendancepage"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

If I create new tabs project, then the component is working fine. But its giving issues in my project. I also tried by removing methods called on the ionPageDidEnter() for all the pages.

Does anyone know what could be the possible issue ?

Comment: it's 1 second slow you can use ionic2-super-tabs.

Comment: I want tabs for footer

Comment: yea its also done by ionic2-super-tabs @Shrutika

Comment: if you need then i will share this code using ionic2-super-tabs

Comment: @Utpaul I have read the readme file but didnt find how to set it as footer. Can you please explain

Comment: @Utpaul Also, can I show badges on tabs ?

Comment: need to change tabsPlacement top to bottom

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180240/discussion-between-utpaul-and-shrutika-patil).

Comment: tabsPlacement="bottom" work for me and badges also support. So if you got any problem then knock me.. I already tested that.

Comment: If you got problem it ionic2-super-tabs then you give me access of your code i will fixed it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have debugged and tried to find possible issues. The issue was because of ion-list on pages , which was causing delay in tab switch. When I reduced ion-items to 30, performance increased. I implemented infinite scroll to avoid the performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

thats is mostly dependant on how you load your pages and how you compile your project
try to lazy load you pages and compile your `apk` with `ionic cordova run android --aot --minifyjs --minifycss` this helps in making you app run much faster.

Comment: I have tried this while building apk but it didnt work